# SQL Pivot without knowing values to Pivot on

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Below is my code

```
Select  FromCity, TicketID 
From    #Main
```

Below is the result

```
FromCity    TicketID 
London      Ticket4321  
Miami       Ticket4321
Singapore   Ticket4321
Sydney      Ticket1234
```

I cant use a pivot as I wont know all the names of the cities.
I need my results to look like this.

```
TicketID    FromCities
Ticket4321  London/Miami/Singapore
Ticket1234  Sydney
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using pivot you can use

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([FromCity] varchar(9), [Ticket] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([FromCity], [Ticket])
VALUES
    ('London', 'Ticket4321'),
    ('Miami', 'Ticket4321'),
    ('Singapore', 'Ticket4321'),
    ('Sydney', 'Ticket1234')

select
    Ticket,
    stuff((
        select distinct  '/' + t.[FromCity ]
        from Table1 t

        where t.Ticket = t1.Ticket

        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as name_csv
from Table1 t1
group by Ticket
```

output

```
TicketID    FromCities
Ticket4321  London/Miami/Singapore
Ticket1234  Sydney
```

Comment: Cool, but how do you only return distinct cities in the list?

Comment: @Etienne while generating comma sperated values we can filter by using distinct keyword